# native library in an application Client

Tags: glassfish, jogl

I'm using jogl in an application that is deploeyd from a glassfish server .
I have tested the part using jogl in a jse and it works fine.
When i paste the code and add the libraries and run the programm via netbeans it didn't work.
I get this exception:
**Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jogl in java.library.path**

What can i do to fix this problems ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans under File / Project Properties, select "Run" from the "Categories" tree. In the "VM Options" box, add `-Djava.library.path="<full path to your library>"` *with* the quotation marks.